# Adding days on calculated column from monday to friday

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, date

I need to add a calculated column in SharePoint where I have to add +1 day from Monday to Thursday and +3 on Friday but I don't know how to do it. I did some tests with WEEKDAY without success.

Comment: can you create workflow for each item and apply login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  `WEEKDAY` function like below:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(Today())=2,Today()+1,Today())
```

This will check if today's day is "Monday", If Yes, it will add 1 days to today's date else it will set column value to today's date (Similarly you can add your other conditions to this formula).

**Complete formula**:

```
=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(Today())=2,WEEKDAY(Today())=3,WEEKDAY(Today())=4,WEEKDAY(Today())=5),Today()+1,IF(WEEKDAY(Today())=6,Today()+3,Today()))
```

**Reference**: [WEEKDAY function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/weekday-function-f0aa7aa6-fad7-4e41-aab9-3e77a133f0be)

**Note**:

1. This function returns the day of the week corresponding to a date. The day is given as an integer, ranging from **1 (Sunday) to 7 (Saturday)**, by default.
2. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
3. Return your calculated field as **Date and Time**.

Comment: Hi @MarkR, If this helped you, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below formula:

```
=IF(OR(WEEKDAY([date])=2,WEEKDAY([date])=3,WEEKDAY([date])=4,WEEKDAY([date])=5),[date]+1,IF(WEEKDAY([date])=6,[date]+3,[date]))
```

[image]